# how to solve cpp library confliction within anaconda?

Tags: python, c++, anaconda, lightgbm, anaconda3

I tried to install lightgbm with gpu in anaconda. I used pip in anaconda directly with --install-option='--gpu'. it's built successfully and lib_lightgbm.so links to libstdc++.so under /lib64.

as anaconda has it's own libstdc++.so under anaconda3/lib and it's different from the one under /lib64, when I try to import lightgbm, I got the error saying

```
anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found (required by lib_lightgbm.so)
```

what's the recommend way to keep libstdc++.so in anaconda consistent with lightgbm (or any other libraries) built outside anaconda?

do I need to find the cpp compiler information used by anaconda? where can I find such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [microsoft/LightGBM#5106](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5106#issuecomment-1121925896), when building `lightgbm` from source in a `conda` environment on Linux, the most reliable way to avoid linking to a `libstdc++` that is using a new GLIBCXX version than the one found by `conda` is to use `conda`'s C/C++ compilers.

Like the following.

```bash
# create conda env with lightgbm's dependencies
conda create \
   --name lightgbm-env \
   --yes \
   -c conda-forge \
   python=3.10 \
   numpy \
   scikit-learn \
   scipy

# install `conda`'s C++ build tools into that environment
conda install \
   --name lightgbm-env \
   --yes \
   -c conda-forge \
   python=3.10 \
   cmake \
   gcc_linux-64 \
   gxx_linux-64

# clone LightGBM
git clone \
   --recursive \
   --branch stable \
   https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM.git

# activate the conda env, so that conda's compilers are found first
source activate lightgbm-env

# install lightgbm with `pip`
cd LightGBM/python-package
pip install .
```

**NOTE:** This answer applies to `lightgbm` versions `<=3.3.2.99`.

Comment: I assume this means that the c++ compiler in conda force is quite stable. or installing c++ compiler will update libstdc++ in conda.  but should there be any concern regarding other prebuilt libraries in anaconda? if they are built by older c++ compiler. but I guess that's a different question. many thanks to your help.

Comment: Being built with OLDER `libstdc++` (specifically, `libstdc++` with an older maximum `GLIBCXX` version than what `conda` provides) will not cause compatibility issues like the one you reported. This type of error happens in the opposite situation...linking against a NEWER `libstdc++` at build time than the one that is linked to dynamically at runtime (i.e. when importing the library).

Comment: yes, it's ok for this specific issue. my concern is that mixing cpp libraries compiled by different version of compilers could cause strange errors like coredump or hang